# Create shortcut to close current browser tab?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox

With `Ctrl-W` I can close the current tab.

Can I create another key shortcut that closes the current tab?

Answer (score 0):

You may use as tool [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/),
with as example the following script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Google Chrome
F11::Send ^w
```

This will, when <kbd>F11</kbd> is pressed, send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,
but only to processes whose window title contains "Google Chrome".